# My enemies stop moving if i move my player

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjDi8.jpg

Sorry for the lag, but as visible my enemies(green) spawn but after if i move my player(gray) they sometimes stop moving until i move my player again.

But even after moving my player the pre existing enemies dont move closer to the player and retain their distance to the player

[this is the file which contains the main loop of the game](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/ivirelepur.rb)

[this is the file which contains the player class](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/pihiwosozu.lua)

[this is the file which contains the enemy class](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/idarimeroq.py)

[and this is the file which is the main run file](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/iwuhejiyev.properties)

i feel the problem exists in my main loop class which is as follows:

```py
import pygame, random
from Folder.scripts.TopDown.script_files.td_Player import Player
from Folder.scripts.TopDown.script_files.td_enemy import Enemy
from Folder.scripts.TopDown.script_files.td_colours import colours

pygame.init()

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.FPS = 60
        self.WIDTH = self.HEIGHT = 1280
        self.MAP = pygame.Surface((self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT))
        self.enemies = []

    def main(self,WINDOW ,clock):

        WINDOW.fill(colours['white'])
        player = Player()

        camera_pos = (0, 0)
        enemy_time = 0

        run = True
        while run:

            clock.tick(self.FPS)

            enemy_y = random.randint(0, 1220)
            enemy_x = random.randint(0, 1220)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False

            current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            if current_time > enemy_time:
                enemy_time = current_time + 1000
                self.enemies.append(Enemy(enemy_y, enemy_x))

            camera_pos = player.movement(camera_pos)

            self.WindowUpdate(WINDOW, player, camera_pos)

        pygame.quit()

    def WindowUpdate(self,WINDOW, player, camera_pos):

        player_x, player_y = player.playerMove()

        WINDOW.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.MAP.fill(colours['gray'])
        player.renderPlayer(self.MAP)
        WINDOW.blit(self.MAP, camera_pos)

        for e in self.enemies:
            e.renderEnemy(WINDOW)
            e.enemyMovement(player_x, player_y)

        pygame.display.update()
```

`Enemy` class:

```py
import pygame, os, random, math

pygame.init()

# current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
#         if current_time > self.enemy_time:
#             self.enemy_time = current_time + 1000
#             self.enemies.append()

class Enemy:

    def __init__(self, enemy_y, enemy_x):
        self.ENEMY_HEIGHT = self.ENEMY_WIDTH = 64
        self.ENEMY_ACCELERATION = 5

        self.enemy_rect = pygame.Rect(enemy_x, enemy_y, self.ENEMY_HEIGHT, self.ENEMY_WIDTH)

        self.ENEMY = {
            'up': pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(
                os.path.join(r'C:\Users\ajeen\PycharmProjects\Games\Folder\scripts\TopDown\assets', 'enemy_up.png')),
                (self.ENEMY_HEIGHT, self.ENEMY_WIDTH)),

            'down': pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(
                os.path.join(r'C:\Users\ajeen\PycharmProjects\Games\Folder\scripts\TopDown\assets', 'enemy_down.png')),
                (self.ENEMY_HEIGHT, self.ENEMY_WIDTH)),

            'left': pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(
                os.path.join(r'C:\Users\ajeen\PycharmProjects\Games\Folder\scripts\TopDown\assets', 'enemy_left.png')),
                (self.ENEMY_HEIGHT, self.ENEMY_WIDTH)),

            'right': pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(
                os.path.join(r'C:\Users\ajeen\PycharmProjects\Games\Folder\scripts\TopDown\assets', 'enemy_right.png')),
                (self.ENEMY_HEIGHT, self.ENEMY_WIDTH))
        }

        self.enemy_state = 'up'

    def enemyMovement(self, player_x, player_y):
        ene_x, ene_y = player_x - self.enemy_rect.x, player_y - self.enemy_rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(ene_x, ene_y)
        ene_x, ene_y = ene_x // dist, ene_y // dist

        self.enemy_rect.x += ene_x * self.ENEMY_ACCELERATION
        self.enemy_rect.y += ene_y * self.ENEMY_ACCELERATION
        print(self.enemy_rect.x, self.enemy_rect.y)

    def renderEnemy(self, WINDOW):
        WINDOW.blit(self.ENEMY[self.enemy_state] , (self.enemy_rect.x, self.enemy_rect.y))
```

I hope the imgur link to the vid showcasing my problem gets embedded. Any input or help will be appreciated

Comment: *"i feel the problem exists in my main loop"* - Why? There doesn't seem to be a problem in your main loop.

Comment: i felt so because it is in the main loop that im calling my enemies right, so the problem must be there, it was just an assumption, is the problem in my enemy class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `ene_x // dist` and `ene_y // dist` is always 0. To calculate the movement, you must use the `/` (division) operator rather than the `//` (floor division) operator

<s>`ene_x, ene_y = ene_x // dist, ene_y // dist`</s>

```py
ene_x, ene_y = ene_x / dist, ene_y / dist
```

---

Since [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen, a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data.

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

The fraction part of the movement gets lost when the position of the object incremented:

> ```py
> self.enemy_rect.x += ene_x * self.ENEMY_ACCELERATION
> self.enemy_rect.y += ene_y * self.ENEMY_ACCELERATION
> ```

If you want to store object positions with floating point accuracy, you have to store the location of the object in separate variables respectively attributes and to synchronize the `pygame.Rect` object. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates and assign it to the location (e.g. `.topleft`) of the rectangle:

```py
x, y = # floating point coordinates
rect.topleft = round(x), round(y)
```

Add floating point coordinates to the `Enemy` class:

```py
class Enemy:

    def __init__(self, enemy_y, enemy_x):
        # [...]

        self.enemy_rect = pygame.Rect(enemy_x, enemy_y, self.ENEMY_HEIGHT, self.ENEMY_WIDTH)
        self.x, self.y = self.enemy_rect.topleft

        # [...]
        

    def enemyMovement(self, player_x, player_y):
        ene_x, ene_y = player_x - self.x, player_y - self.y
        dist = math.hypot(ene_x, ene_y)
        ene_x, ene_y = ene_x / dist, ene_y / dist

        self.x += ene_x * self.ENEMY_ACCELERATION
        self.y += ene_y * self.ENEMY_ACCELERATION
        self.enemy_rect = round(self.x), round(self.y)
```

Comment: oh thank you ill try running it :D

Comment: it works! thank you so very much!!